# Disabling certificate revocation checks in Mule

Tags: mule

I am having an issue where service calls that I am making cannot validate server certificates presented by the TMG as part of connecting to the service. The certificate URLS from the TMG address are not reachable from the target servers. This is causing 30 second timeouts for new connections.

Is there a way to disable certificate revocation checks in Mule to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Mule HTTP endpoints, then this would vary, if you're using http transport you can create a custom message dispatcher and allow http client to ignore the certificates, otherwise you can manually install the certificates in the keystore so you don't get SSL errors.